# How do I print just the values inside of sets that are inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary which is `flightterminals={"Terminal 1":{"1", "2", "3"},"Terminal 2":{"1", "2", "3"}, "Terminal 3":{"1", "2", "3"}}`

What do I do to print just what is inside of the sets with no quotations, brackets, or braces. However, I do want commas.

The output should look like this:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

I have tried `x, y, z=flightterminals`.

Comment: This is doable. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried `x, y, z=flightterminals`. Also, how does what I have tried have to do with printing just values and commas? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current approach, `x`, `y` and `z` will become the keys of the dictionary, i.e. `Terminal 1`, `Terminal 2` and `Terminal 3`.

You could then index the dictionary to retrieve the values, which are the sets you are interested in.

Since [sets are unordered collections](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), you can sort the elements using the [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function.

Note that `sorted` will return a `list` like this: `['1', '2', '3']`, and you can then use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) to join up the elements of that list with commas in between.

```
flightterminals = {
    "Terminal 1": {"1", "2", "3"},
    "Terminal 2": {"1", "2", "3"},
    "Terminal 3": {"1", "2", "3"}
}

x, y, z = flightterminals
for key in x, y, z:
    print(", ".join(sorted(flightterminals[key])))
```

While the above approach is fine and will work assuming you have 3 keys in the dictionary, it would break in the case of a different number of keys. As such, it is worth generalizing it to handle an arbitrary number of keys.

You can do this by directly obtaining the values from the `flightterminals` dictionary using the [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict%20values#dict.values) method.

With this approach, the code is both simpler and more general:

```
for value in flightterminals.values():
    print(", ".join(sorted(value)))
```

In both cases, the output is as follows:

```
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```